# keystoneauth1.exceptions.http.Unauthorized

Tags: openstack-nova, openstack-neutron

2023-12-06 16:35:53.151 1533 INFO nova.compute.claims [None req-6e11fb26-94b5-456e-9c0f-c95ddcf95957 90d604a6f0b44afb85d4805b88e4d01c 7213168c18a64ef79ac2bbade35cd663 - - default default] [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07] Claim successful on node node1
2023-12-06 16:35:53.319 1533 INFO nova.virt.libvirt.driver [None req-6e11fb26-94b5-456e-9c0f-c95ddcf95957 90d604a6f0b44afb85d4805b88e4d01c 7213168c18a64ef79ac2bbade35cd663 - - default default] [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07] Ignoring supplied device name: /dev/vda. Libvirt can't honour user-supplied dev names
2023-12-06 16:35:53.394 1533 INFO nova.virt.libvirt.driver [None req-6e11fb26-94b5-456e-9c0f-c95ddcf95957 90d604a6f0b44afb85d4805b88e4d01c 7213168c18a64ef79ac2bbade35cd663 - - default default] [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07] Creating image(s)
2023-12-06 16:35:53.399 1533 INFO oslo.privsep.daemon [None req-6e11fb26-94b5-456e-9c0f-c95ddcf95957 90d604a6f0b44afb85d4805b88e4d01c 7213168c18a64ef79ac2bbade35cd663 - - default default] Running privsep helper: ['sudo', 'nova-rootwrap', '/etc/nova/rootwrap.conf', 'privsep-helper', '--config-file', '/etc/nova/nova.conf', '--config-file', '/etc/nova/nova-compute.conf', '--privsep_context', 'nova.privsep.sys_admin_pctxt', '--privsep_sock_path', '/tmp/tmpi9t71bni/privsep.sock']
2023-12-06 16:35:53.934 1533 INFO oslo.privsep.daemon [None req-6e11fb26-94b5-456e-9c0f-c95ddcf95957 90d604a6f0b44afb85d4805b88e4d01c 7213168c18a64ef79ac2bbade35cd663 - - default default] Spawned new privsep daemon via rootwrap
2023-12-06 16:35:53.844 1569 INFO oslo.privsep.daemon [-] privsep daemon starting
2023-12-06 16:35:53.846 1569 INFO oslo.privsep.daemon [-] privsep process running with uid/gid: 0/0
2023-12-06 16:35:53.848 1569 INFO oslo.privsep.daemon [-] privsep process running with capabilities (eff/prm/inh): CAP_CHOWN|CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE|CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH|CAP_FOWNER|CAP_NET_ADMIN|CAP_SYS_ADMIN/CAP_CHOWN|CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE|CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH|CAP_FOWNER|CAP_NET_ADMIN|CAP_SYS_ADMIN/none
2023-12-06 16:35:53.848 1569 INFO oslo.privsep.daemon [-] privsep daemon running as pid 1569
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [None req-6e11fb26-94b5-456e-9c0f-c95ddcf95957 90d604a6f0b44afb85d4805b88e4d01c 7213168c18a64ef79ac2bbade35cd663 - - default default] Instance failed network setup after 1 attempt(s): keystoneauth1.exceptions.http.Unauthorized: The request you have made requires authentication. (HTTP 401) (Request-ID: req-44eaaa35-b3fe-424b-a2c1-9db9d4824f49)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1965, in _allocate_network_async
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager     nwinfo = self.network_api.allocate_for_instance(
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/network/neutron.py", line 1216, in allocate_for_instance
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager     created_port_ids = self._update_ports_for_instance(
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/network/neutron.py", line 1352, in _update_ports_for_instance
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager     with excutils.save_and_reraise_exception():
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 227, in **exit**
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager     self.force_reraise()
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 200, in force_reraise
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager     raise self.value
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/network/neutron.py", line 1327, in _update_ports_for_instance
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager     updated_port = self._update_port(
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/network/neutron.py", line 583, in _update_port
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager     port_response = port_client.update_port(port_id, port_req_body)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/network/neutron.py", line 196, in wrapper
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager     ret = obj(*args, **kwargs)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 828, in update_port
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager     return self._update_resource(self.port_path % (port), body=body,
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/network/neutron.py", line 196, in wrapper
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager     ret = obj(*args, **kwargs)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 2548, in _update_resource
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager     return self.put(path, **kwargs)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/network/neutron.py", line 196, in wrapper
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager     ret = obj(*args, **kwargs)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 365, in put
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager     return self.retry_request("PUT", action, body=body,
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/network/neutron.py", line 196, in wrapper
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager     ret = obj(*args, **kwargs)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 333, in retry_request
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager     return self.do_request(method, action, body=body,
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/network/neutron.py", line 196, in wrapper
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager     ret = obj(*args, **kwargs)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 284, in do_request
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager     resp, replybody = self.httpclient.do_request(action, method, body=body,
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/neutronclient/client.py", line 341, in do_request
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager     self._check_uri_length(url)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/neutronclient/client.py", line 334, in _check_uri_length
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager     uri_len = len(self.endpoint_url) + len(url)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/neutronclient/client.py", line 348, in endpoint_url
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager     return self.get_endpoint()
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keystoneauth1/adapter.py", line 291, in get_endpoint
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager     return self.session.get_endpoint(auth or self.auth, **kwargs)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keystoneauth1/session.py", line 1243, in get_endpoint
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager     return auth.get_endpoint(self, **kwargs)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keystoneauth1/identity/base.py", line 375, in get_endpoint
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager     endpoint_data = self.get_endpoint_data(
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keystoneauth1/identity/base.py", line 271, in get_endpoint_data
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager     service_catalog = self.get_access(session).service_catalog
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keystoneauth1/identity/base.py", line 134, in get_access
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager     self.auth_ref = self.get_auth_ref(session)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keystoneauth1/identity/generic/base.py", line 208, in get_auth_ref
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager     return self._plugin.get_auth_ref(session, **kwargs)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keystoneauth1/identity/v3/base.py", line 188, in get_auth_ref
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager     resp = session.post(token_url, json=body, headers=headers,
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keystoneauth1/session.py", line 1149, in post
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager     return self.request(url, 'POST', **kwargs)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keystoneauth1/session.py", line 986, in request
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager     raise exceptions.from_response(resp, method, url)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager keystoneauth1.exceptions.http.Unauthorized: The request you have made requires authentication. (HTTP 401) (Request-ID: req-44eaaa35-b3fe-424b-a2c1-9db9d4824f49)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.187 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [None req-6e11fb26-94b5-456e-9c0f-c95ddcf95957 90d604a6f0b44afb85d4805b88e4d01c 7213168c18a64ef79ac2bbade35cd663 - - default default] [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07] Instance failed to spawn: keystoneauth1.exceptions.http.Unauthorized: The request you have made requires authentication. (HTTP 401) (Request-ID: req-44eaaa35-b3fe-424b-a2c1-9db9d4824f49)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07] Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 2849, in _build_resources
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     yield resources
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 2607, in _build_and_run_instance
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     self.driver.spawn(context, instance, image_meta,
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 4385, in spawn
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     xml = self._get_guest_xml(context, instance, network_info,
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 7518, in _get_guest_xml
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     network_info_str = str(network_info)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/network/model.py", line 620, in **str**
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     return self._sync_wrapper(fn, *args, **kwargs)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/network/model.py", line 603, in _sync_wrapper
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     self.wait()
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/network/model.py", line 635, in wait
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     self[:] = self._gt.wait()
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/eventlet/greenthread.py", line 181, in wait
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     return self._exit_event.wait()
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/eventlet/event.py", line 125, in wait
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     result = hub.switch()
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/eventlet/hubs/hub.py", line 313, in switch
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     return self.greenlet.switch()
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/eventlet/greenthread.py", line 221, in main
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     result = function(*args, **kwargs)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/utils.py", line 654, in context_wrapper
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     return func(*args, **kwargs)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1987, in _allocate_network_async
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     raise e
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1965, in _allocate_network_async
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     nwinfo = self.network_api.allocate_for_instance(
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/network/neutron.py", line 1216, in allocate_for_instance
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     created_port_ids = self._update_ports_for_instance(
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/network/neutron.py", line 1352, in _update_ports_for_instance
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     with excutils.save_and_reraise_exception():
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 227, in **exit**
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     self.force_reraise()
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 200, in force_reraise
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     raise self.value
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/network/neutron.py", line 1327, in _update_ports_for_instance
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     updated_port = self._update_port(
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/network/neutron.py", line 583, in _update_port
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     port_response = port_client.update_port(port_id, port_req_body)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/network/neutron.py", line 196, in wrapper
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     ret = obj(*args, **kwargs)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 828, in update_port
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     return self._update_resource(self.port_path % (port), body=body,
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/network/neutron.py", line 196, in wrapper
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     ret = obj(*args, **kwargs)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 2548, in _update_resource
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     return self.put(path, **kwargs)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/network/neutron.py", line 196, in wrapper
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     ret = obj(*args, **kwargs)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 365, in put
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     return self.retry_request("PUT", action, body=body,
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/network/neutron.py", line 196, in wrapper
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     ret = obj(*args, **kwargs)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 333, in retry_request
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     return self.do_request(method, action, body=body,
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/network/neutron.py", line 196, in wrapper
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     ret = obj(*args, **kwargs)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/neutronclient/v2_0/client.py", line 284, in do_request
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     resp, replybody = self.httpclient.do_request(action, method, body=body,
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/neutronclient/client.py", line 341, in do_request
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     self._check_uri_length(url)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/neutronclient/client.py", line 334, in _check_uri_length
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     uri_len = len(self.endpoint_url) + len(url)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/neutronclient/client.py", line 348, in endpoint_url
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     return self.get_endpoint()
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keystoneauth1/adapter.py", line 291, in get_endpoint
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     return self.session.get_endpoint(auth or self.auth, **kwargs)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keystoneauth1/session.py", line 1243, in get_endpoint
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     return auth.get_endpoint(self, **kwargs)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keystoneauth1/identity/base.py", line 375, in get_endpoint
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     endpoint_data = self.get_endpoint_data(
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keystoneauth1/identity/base.py", line 271, in get_endpoint_data
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     service_catalog = self.get_access(session).service_catalog
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keystoneauth1/identity/base.py", line 134, in get_access
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     self.auth_ref = self.get_auth_ref(session)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keystoneauth1/identity/generic/base.py", line 208, in get_auth_ref
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     return self._plugin.get_auth_ref(session, **kwargs)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keystoneauth1/identity/v3/base.py", line 188, in get_auth_ref
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     resp = session.post(token_url, json=body, headers=headers,
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keystoneauth1/session.py", line 1149, in post
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     return self.request(url, 'POST', **kwargs)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keystoneauth1/session.py", line 986, in request
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]     raise exceptions.from_response(resp, method, url)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07] keystoneauth1.exceptions.http.Unauthorized: The request you have made requires authentication. (HTTP 401) (Request-ID: req-44eaaa35-b3fe-424b-a2c1-9db9d4824f49)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.192 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07]
2023-12-06 16:35:54.195 1533 INFO nova.compute.manager [None req-6e11fb26-94b5-456e-9c0f-c95ddcf95957 90d604a6f0b44afb85d4805b88e4d01c 7213168c18a64ef79ac2bbade35cd663 - - default default] [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07] Terminating instance
2023-12-06 16:35:54.434 1533 WARNING nova.compute.manager [None req-6e11fb26-94b5-456e-9c0f-c95ddcf95957 90d604a6f0b44afb85d4805b88e4d01c 7213168c18a64ef79ac2bbade35cd663 - - default default] Could not clean up failed build, not rescheduling. Error: The request you have made requires authentication. (HTTP 401) (Request-ID: req-9aaa8fb9-8731-4b75-b28d-97001e175382): keystoneauth1.exceptions.http.Unauthorized: The request you have made requires authentication. (HTTP 401) (Request-ID: req-9aaa8fb9-8731-4b75-b28d-97001e175382)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.557 1533 ERROR nova.compute.manager [None req-6e11fb26-94b5-456e-9c0f-c95ddcf95957 90d604a6f0b44afb85d4805b88e4d01c 7213168c18a64ef79ac2bbade35cd663 - - default default] [instance: 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07] Build of instance 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07 aborted: The request you have made requires authentication. (HTTP 401) (Request-ID: req-44eaaa35-b3fe-424b-a2c1-9db9d4824f49): nova.exception.BuildAbortException: Build of instance 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07 aborted: The request you have made requires authentication. (HTTP 401) (Request-ID: req-44eaaa35-b3fe-424b-a2c1-9db9d4824f49)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.840 1533 WARNING nova.compute.manager [None req-6e11fb26-94b5-456e-9c0f-c95ddcf95957 90d604a6f0b44afb85d4805b88e4d01c 7213168c18a64ef79ac2bbade35cd663 - - default default] Failed to update network info cache when cleaning up allocated networks. Stale VIFs may be left on this host.Error: The request you have made requires authentication. (HTTP 401) (Request-ID: req-8b5df6a7-5e12-40b8-9d07-0f83019893f7): keystoneauth1.exceptions.http.Unauthorized: The request you have made requires authentication. (HTTP 401) (Request-ID: req-8b5df6a7-5e12-40b8-9d07-0f83019893f7)
2023-12-06 16:35:54.892 1533 INFO nova.scheduler.client.report [None req-6e11fb26-94b5-456e-9c0f-c95ddcf95957 90d604a6f0b44afb85d4805b88e4d01c 7213168c18a64ef79ac2bbade35cd663 - - default default] Deleted allocations for instance 01bf8fac-3173-4465-aa7f-f21661674d07

checked nova.conf,keystone.conf,neutron.conf but no solutions